# Как включить полноэкранный режим в приложении WPF без обрезания краев и панели задач?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я пишу приложение на WPF. Хочу сделать кастомную рамку приложения, но во-первых: если поставить текст в самый край приложения и включить полноэкранный режим, то можно заметить что пол текста не видно, во-вторых: панель задач скрывается - я пробовал ставить максимальную высоту, но если панель задач находится не снизу, а с боку, то это не работает.

Скрин приложения в полноэкранном режиме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин приложения в обычном режиме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя xaml разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="DSF_GEOS_Monitoring.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DSF_GEOS_Monitoring.MVVM.ViewModels"
        xmlns:md="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DSF_GEOS_Monitoring"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DSF-GEOS Monitoring v0.0.1 Beta" 
        Height="500" Width="800"
        WindowStyle="None">
    <!--Add MainViewModel-->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <!--Remove white bar-->
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome 
        CaptionHeight="0"
        ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <!--UI-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--Background-->
        <Canvas Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="{Binding background}"/>

        <!--Title bar-->
        <Canvas Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="{Binding titleBackground}" />

        <TextBlock Text="Test" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button x:Name="buttonChangeTheme" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                    Height="25">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18">
                        <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                            <Path Fill="{Binding foreground}" Data="M12,18C11.11,18 10.26,17.8 9.5,17.45C11.56,16.5 13,14.42 13,12C13,9.58 11.56,7.5 9.5,6.55C10.26,6.2 11.11,6 12,6A6,6 0 0,1 18,12A6,6 0 0,1 12,18M20,8.69V4H15.31L12,0.69L8.69,4H4V8.69L0.69,12L4,15.31V20H8.69L12,23.31L15.31,20H20V15.31L23.31,12L20,8.69Z" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="buttonMinimize" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                    Height="25"
                    Click="buttonMinimize_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18">
                        <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                            <Path Fill="{Binding foreground}" Data="M20,14H4V10H20" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="buttonMaximizeRestore"
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                    Height="25"
                    Click="buttonMaximizeRestore_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18">
                        <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                            <Path Fill="{Binding foreground}" Data="M4,4H20V20H4V4M6,8V18H18V8H6Z" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="buttonClose"
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                    Height="25"
                    Click="buttonClose_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18">
                        <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                            <Path Fill="{Binding foreground}" Data="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Это мой код в MainWindow.xaml.cs:
using System.Windows;

```
namespace DSF_GEOS_Monitoring
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void buttonMaximizeRestore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            else 
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void buttonMinimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Margin` установите, да и все.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте после InitializeComponent();

```
MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
```